# When to use subprocess.call() or subprocess.Popen(), running airodump

Tags: python, subprocess

I have this little script that puts your wireless device into monitor mode. It does an airodump  scan and then after terminating the scan dumps the output to file.txt or a variable, so then I can scrape the BSSID and whatever other info I may need.

I feel I haven't grasped the concept or difference between `subprocess.call()` and `subprocess.Popen()`.

This is what I currently have:

```
def setup_device(): 
    try:
        output = open("file.txt", "w")
        put_device_down = subprocess.call(["ifconfig", "wlan0", "down"])
        put_device_mon = subprocess.call(["iwconfig", "wlan0", "mode", "monitor"]) 
        put_device_up = subprocess.call(["iwconfig", "wlano", "up"])
        start_device = subprocess.call(["airmon-ng", "start", "wlan0"])
        scanned_networks = subprocess.Popen(["airodump-ng", "wlan0"], stdout = output)  
        time.sleep(10)  
        scanned_networks.terminate()

    except Exception, e:
         print "Error:", e
```

I am still clueless about where and when and in which way to use `subprocess.call()` and `subprocess.Popen()`

The thing that I think is confusing me most is the `stdout` and `stderr` args. What is  `PIPE`?

Another thing that I could possibly fix myself once I get a better grasp is this:

When `running subprocess.Popen()` and running airodump, the console window pops up showing the scan. Is there a way to hide this from the user to sort of clean things up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to use `Popen()` if you don't want to. The other functions in the module, such as `.call()` use `Popen()`, give you a simpler API to do what you want.

All console applications have 3 'file' streams: `stdin` for input, and `stdout` and `stderr` for output. The application decides what to write where; usually error and diagnostic information to `stderr`, the rest to `stdout`. If you want to capture the output for either of these outputs in your Python program, you specify the `subprocess.PIPE` argument so that the 'stream' is redirected into your program. Hence the name.

If you want to capture the output of the `airodump-ng wlan0` command, it's easiest to use the [`subprocess.check_output()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) function; it takes care of the `PIPE` argument for you:

```
scanned_networks = subprocess.check_output(["airodump-ng", "wlan0"])
```

Now `output` contains whatever `airodump-ng` wrote to its `stdout` stream.

If you need to have more control over the process, then you do need to use the `Popen()` class:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["airodump-ng", "wlan0"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in proc.stdout:
    # do something with line
proc.terminate()
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I tried using check_output for my scan before but had to resort to Popen() as my scan will run infinitely until I manually press ctrl-c in the terminal that its running as I believe only Popen() has the terminate() method? Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @JakePoulter: Indeed, if `airdump-ng` keeps running until terminated, you'd need to use `Popen()` with `stdout` redirected to your python program. I included an example.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. I see how that works, but that makes the script go in an infinite loop, as airodump runs until you manually stop the process, therefore making the for loop keep writing the lines

Comment: You'll have to decide when you have read enough from the pipe and stop the process; I don't know what you are looking for here. :-)

Comment: Once you have what you need, use `break` to end the loop.